# Scroll up and down by drag the table

Tags: java, scroll, libgdx, drag

```
 table1.addListener(new InputListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
           scroll=y;
            System.out.print(scroll);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void touchDragged(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {

            table1.setPosition((scroll+(y)));
        }});
```

I want to scroll my table up and down by dragging my table (like Facebook on phone) I can't make this math thing on the `Y` I don't know why when I drag it it goes crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters `x` and `y` in the methods of `InputListener` are local coordinates (i.e. relative to your `table`), so you need to convert them to `table`'s parent coordinate system:

```
table.addListener(new InputListener() {

    Vector2 vec = new Vector2();

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        table.localToParentCoordinates(vec.set(x, y));
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void touchDragged(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
        float oldTouchY = vec.y;
        table.localToParentCoordinates(vec.set(x, y));
        table.moveBy(0f, vec.y - oldTouchY);
    }
});
```

By the way, using `ScrollPane` will probably be much better and convenient solution in your case: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui#scrollpane

**Upd:**

Actually, since you only need `deltaY` you can do this without converting coordinates:

```
table.addListener(new InputListener() {

    float touchY;

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        touchY = y;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void touchDragged(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
        // since you move your table along with pointer, your touchY will be the same in table's local coordinates
        float deltaY = y - touchY;
        table.moveBy(0f, deltaY);
    }
});
```